# Update dataframe to change leaflet output based on users choice in shiny

Tags: shiny, leaflet

I'm new to shiny and I have tried multiple ways to update the leaflet output based on two selectinput, the first chooses the data frame to use and the second what to filter on. this bit is working but I don't seem to be able to pass this to the leaflet proxy, any thoughts would be appreciated

```
poldat <- vroom::vroom("F:/ming1/data/poldat.csv")
meddat <- vroom::vroom("F:/ming1/data/meddat.csv")
medlist <- vroom::vroom("F:/ming1/data/ddl1.csv")
pollist <- vroom::vroom("F:/ming1/data/ddl2.csv")
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(vroom)
ui <- bootstrapPage(
  tags$style(type = "text/css", "html, body {width:100%;height:100%}"),
  leafletOutput("map", width = "50%", height = "100%"),
  absolutePanel(top = 10, right = 10,
                selectInput('var1', 'Select the area you wish to view', choices = c("choose" = "","police","Medical")), 
                selectInput('var2', 'Select the area you would like to view' ,choices =c("choose" = "")),

  ))



server <- function(input, output, session){
  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet(map1) %>% addTiles() %>%
      fitBounds(~min(long), ~min(lat), ~max(long), ~max(lat))


  })
  observe({
    a_option <- input$var1
      if (a_option == "police") {
      updateSelectInput(session, "var2", choices = c("choose" = "",pollist$row1))
      }else{
      updateSelectInput(session, "var2", choices = c("choose" = "",medlist$row1))
    }

})

  observe({
        catreq <- input$var1
        #mapfilt <- input$var2
    mydf<- input$var1
    if (mydf == "police") {
      mydf = poldat
    }else{
      mydf = meddat

    }

   mycol <- input$var1
    if (mycol == "police") {
      mycol = "fallswithin"
    }else{
      mycol = "healtharea"
    }

    map1 <-  subset(mydf, mycol == input$var2)
    leafletProxy("map", data = map1[2:3]) %>% addTiles()# %>% 
    addMarkers(clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions(),label = paste("test"))

    }) 


}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Hi, your example is not reproducible because we don't have access to your data. Please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to know how to make a reproducible example. Also, you can remove the code that is not essential for this question, such as the `CSS` part

Comment: The poldat and meddat csv files contain the long and lat with some other features that will be used later, i just want to place markers dependent on which df has been chosen, if that is any help

Comment: its the changing of the df and filtering of the df and providing that info to leaflet that I cant seem to manage.

Comment: That does not make your example reproducible. Use `dput` on a subset of your data to generate the code to reproduce it and put this code in your post